# Macro for reading bit not working

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to write a macro in C that gets a byte (char) and an index, then it reads the `index`th bit from that byte.
This is what I got:

```
#define READBIT(byte, index) (byte) & (1 << (index))
```

And this is how I check it:

```
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    printf("%d", READBIT('a', i));
}
```

It prints `0643200001`.

Why isn't it working and how do I fix it?

Comment: The first bit of 'a' is 1 so 1 will be printed 8 times

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice, but now it's still not working.

Comment: @turbulencetoo How do I change the macro to return just `0` and `1`?

Comment: @shoham, see Paul Roub's answer below

Comment: Dunno why Paul Roub deleted his answer... it looked pretty good to me!

Comment: `#define READBIT(byte, index) !!((byte) & (1 << (index)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define READBIT(byte, index) (((unsigned)(byte) >> (index)) & 1)
```

Noting that `>>` and `<<` are better defined for unsigned values.

Comment: Cool, but why is this `#define READBIT(byte, index) ((byte) & (1 << (index)) >> (index))` wrong?

Comment: @shoham: `<<` and `>>` have higher precedence than `&`, so you'd need `#define READBIT(byte, index) ( ((byte) & 1<<(index)) >> (index) )`.

Comment: Masking down to the bit and then shifting that down will do the job, as well... though it looks like one operation more than is necessary.  It's perhaps worth noting that `>>` is better defined for unsigned values.  So `READBIT(byte, index) (((unsigned int)(byte) >> (index)) & 1)` is probably better.

Comment: I tried with my gcc and at least they don't compile to the same instructions; but I think more important than performance is the readability. And your version is more readable, I'd say. I just wanted to explain to Shoham why his way didn't work. And +1 for mentioning that bit stuff should (almost) always be done on unsigned types (maybe add this to your answer).

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked some time ago and I see from the comments that someone deleted their answer which may have addressed the 'why isn't it working' part of the OPs question.  I'll add my 2 cents

It is working, just not how you expected it to and it boils down to the usage of the shift operator.  'a' has a decimal value of 97 or '0110 0001' in binary.  Your macro

```
#define READBIT(byte, index) (byte) & (1 << (index))
```

takes the 1 and shifts it **left** some number (7 to 0) and does a unary and against the binary of 'a', so for example:

```
if index = 7 then '0110 0001' & '1000 000' which is '0000 0000' or 0
if index = 6 then '0110 0001' & '0100 000' which is '0100 0000' or 64
if index = 5 then '0110 0001' & '0010 000' which is '0010 0000' or 32
```

and so forth, and indeed this is what your output shows.  To produce the 1's and 0's as is expected and as has been correctly pointed out in the other answer, you really want to shift the byte **right** some number (7 to 0) and do the unary operation against 1 like so

```
#define READBIT(byte, index) (((byte) >> (index)) & 1)
```

then we would get

```
                   v------>v
if index = 7 then '0110 0001' shifted right 7 becomes '0000 0000'
              and '0000 0000' & '0000 0001' is '0000 0000' or 0

                    v----->v
if index = 6 then '0110 0001' shifted right 6 becomes '0000 0001'
              and '0000 0001' & '0000 0001' is '0000 0001' or 1

                     v---->v
if index = 5 then '0110 0001' shifted right 5 becomes '0000 0011'
              and '0000 0011' & '0000 0001' is '0000 0001' or 1
```

and so forth.

Alternatively, the original macro could be fixed by adding a '!= 0' to the result which would then return true (1) or false (0). The original macro would then look like

```
#define READBIT(byte, index) ((byte) & (1 << (index)) != 0)
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to somebody in the future.